# Using library project, "Sorry! The application... stopped unexpectedly"

Tags: android, eclipse, library-project

I’m having trouble using Eclipse ADT projects as libraries. I have three projects in eclipse: ToolProject, AppProject, DevProject.

The ToolProject contains classes I use in several apps (I actually have AppProject_2, as well, something completely different). In Properties, Android -> IsLibrary is ticked.

The AppProject contains the top-level app code, Activity, manifest, etc. It works – I can run it on my phone (IsLibrary ticked or unticked – both fine). Properties -> Android Library references ToolProject. The BuildPath does not reference ToolProject, in any tab.

The DevProject is so I can download and run the lastest draft on my phone, without clobbering the existing AppProject that’s running there. I have created a new project, different launcher icon, different package. The Activity just subclasses AppProject’s Activity.

I can’t get DevProject to run on my phone. The console shows the normal messages. Logcat shows nothing for the launch. On the phone, I quickly get the “Sorry! The application DevProject (…) has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again.” Nothing – no screen – from the app appears.

AppProject is marked as a library. I’ve tried DevProject with Library-reference to both AppProject and DevProject, and to just AppProject. Neither are in DevProject’s BuildPath tabs.

Can someone tell me where to go and what to do there? I’m sorry for such a vague question, but I don’t know what to tweak. Pointers to the relevant documentation or previous questions would be great.

Disclaimer: I have searched for discussions. I have read Android’s Manifest documentation. But I remain unenlightened.

Comment: show me your error code please

Comment: Post your logcat error.

Comment: Grumble. There really was nothing in logcat. But... when I got your requests, I shut down eclipse, disconnected the phone, and brought it all up again. And ran it so I could post a screenshot of an empty logcat. Except... now logcat had stuff in it. I suppose somehow eclipse had lost it's connection to logcat. My apologies, and thanks for your time. [Grumble eclipse grumble.]

Answer (score 0):

The app startup, in onCreate, used files from the assets/ folder. I had forgotten to copy these from AppProject to DevProject.

Problem solved.